# Accessing request data of all requests that is being received with Flask

Tags: python, flask

So, I want to write this Python code that wants to assess data in requests I am getting and act accordingly. I have many different endpoints and I'd like a way to access the request data for all requests without creating manually every possible endpoint.
Is there a way to do it with Flask/Bottle? A proxy of sorts

Comment: What do you mean 'without creating every possible endpoint'? How can you have many different endpoints without creating them? Do you mean you want a wildcard endpoint (e.g. an endpoint that will capture any endpoint request)?

Comment: I have a few services that I want to route the requests to according to data I'll get in the requests to many different endpoints. I want to be able to route to them the requests. Let's say, I have 7 applications for each day of the week. If in a request I am receiving there's a word Monday in one of the fields, I'll get the request forwarded to the Monday application. Does that make any sense?

Comment: @PavelZagalsky: that's something different; you are then routing requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a function to be called before every request with the [`@app.before_request` decorator](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.before_request):

```
@app.before_request
def handle_every_request():
    # ...
```

If this function returns anything other than `None`, it'll be used as the response and no views will be called. This would let you create any number of routing options.

Another option is to use the [`request_started` signal](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.request_started), see the [*Signals* documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/signals/):

```
from flask import request_started

@request_started.connect_via(app)
def handle_every_request(sender, **kwargs):
    # ...
```

The above listens to requests for the specific Flask `app` instance. Use `@request_started.connect` if you want to listen to **all** requests for all apps. Signals just listen, they don't route, however.

In general, both Flask and Bottle are *WSGI* applications. WSGI supports wrapping such applications in [*WSGI middleware*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface#WSGI_Middleware), letting you inspect every ingoing and outgoing byte of a request-response pair. This gives you access to the data at a lower level. You could use this to rewrite paths being requested however.

Comment: @PavelZagalsky: I'm not sure you need this though. All you need is a proper route definition with variables, like `/foo/<day_of_the_week>`, then just direct your request to the proper URL path. So don't put the day of the week in the query parameters or POST body, but in the URL.

Comment: I have dozens of endpoints and some may add up soon. I need a sweeping mechanism for any possible requests